# Nullable DatabaseGeneratedOption is not assignable to parameter type Nullable DatabaseGeneratedOption

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, data-annotations

I have my models and mappings on two different files, on my mapping class I do this:

```cs
public class UserEmailMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<UserEmail> {
    HasKey(t => new { t.UserId, t.EmailId });

    Property(t => t.UserId)
        .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);

    Property(t => t.EmailId)
        .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);

    ToTable("UsersEmails");

    Property(t => t.UserId).HasColumnName("UserId");
    Property(t => t.EmailId).HasColumnName("EmailId");
    Property(t => t.IsPrimary).HasColumnName("IsPrimary");

    HasRequired(t => t.Email)
        .WithMany(t => t.UserEmails)
        .HasForeignKey(d => d.EmailId);
    HasRequired(t => t.User)
        .WithMany(t => t.UserEmails)
        .HasForeignKey(d => d.UserId);
}
```

Now, visual studio is complaining about these lines:

```cs
Property(t => t.UserId)
    .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);

Property(t => t.EmailId)
    .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
```

It underlines both `DatabaseGeneratedOption.None`

With this message: `Argument type 'System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption' is not assignable to parameter type 'System.Nullable<System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption>'`.

And I've tried this:

```cs
Nullable<DatabaseGeneratedOption> x1 = DatabaseGeneratedOption.None;
DatabaseGeneratedOption? x2 = DatabaseGeneratedOption.None;

Property(t => t.UserId)
    .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(x1);

Property(t => t.EmailId)
    .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(x2);
```

And here is the unexpected part:

`Argument type 'System.Nullable<System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption> [mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]' is not assignable to parameter type 'System.Nullable<System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption> [mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]'`

Same messages on `x1` and `x2`.

This **does not** cause a compiler error, but still I'd like to fix this. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

Fixed this issue by adding a cast

```
Property(x => x.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None
              as System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption?);
```

Not pretty, but Visual Studio stopped complaining.

Comment: Clean Solution and Rebuild Solution worked for me without having to cast